# order by FIELD() with field name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to order by `FIELD` but each field i want to show state name; below is my current SQL statement

**SQL:**

```
SELECT m.*, s.* 
    FROM mall m 
    LEFT JOIN `state` s 
        ON(m.state_id=s.state_id) 
    WHERE m.mall_status="1" AND m.state_id !="0" 
    ORDER BY FIELD(m.state_id, 14, 12, 13) ASC , m.mall_name ASC 
    LIMIT 0,30
```

**Database:**

```
mall_id   | mall_name        |  state_id
3331410     1 Mont Kiara        14  
3331411     AEON Metro Prima    14  
3331412     AEON Alpha Angle    13  
3331419     Cap Square          13
3331423     Fahrenheit 88       12
3331428     KL Festival City    12
3331430     Low Yat Plaza       12

state_id | state_name
14         Kuala Lumpur
13         Sarawak
12         Sabah
```

**Current Result:**

```
1 Mont Kiara        14  
AEON Metro Prima    14 
Fahrenheit 88       12
KL Festival City    12
Low Yat Plaza       12  
AEON Alpha Angle    13  
Cap Square          13    

//loop
echo $row['mall_name'] . ' ' . $row['state_id']
```

but the result that i want is something like below(*with state name but only show at the top*):

```
Kuala Lumpur  <-- add state_name 
1 Mont Kiara        14  
AEON Metro Prima    14  

Sabah
Fahrenheit 88       12
KL Festival City    12
Low Yat Plaza       12

Sarawak
AEON Alpha Angle    13  
Cap Square          13
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple loop in PHP)

Comment: just you are echoing mal name and state id you should also echo state name..echo $row['state_name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a state changes you need to `echo` the name of the state for the row you're on:

```
echo $row['state_name'];
```

So **at the top** of your loop, you'll need some kind of break condition:

```
if ($state_id != $row["state_id"])
{
    echo $row['state_name'];
    $state_id = $row["state_id"];
}
```

This will ensure the state name gets echoed *one time* before all of the detail is.

Comment: i just get confused, btw thanks, i just need to set again `$state_id = $row["state_id"];`

Comment: @rusly, that is how you do the grouping. At the top of the loop, **outside of it**, set `$state_id = 0` so that it will *break* on the first iteration and you'll get the first state. Now, every time a row comes through and its `state_id` is *different* than what was set on the last break it will *break again* and echo that state name one time and set the *new* break value.